# What's the location of the field descriptions mentioned in the documentation?

Tags: magento2

where can I locate the "field descriptions" referenced in the documentation under event creation?

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/event-create.html

Comment: are you on enterprise version?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Field Description section at the bottom of the Creating Events page, that has a brief description of each field in the Catalog Event Information form.  In addition, there are many references throughout the user guide to the field descriptions in the Configuration Reference. These are often linked to from the "how to" instructions, and in the caption below any configuration-related screenshot. http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/configuration.html.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if you have suggestions for improving the field descriptions -- or anything else -- in the user guide, please sent me a message through the feedback form on the page in question. The feedback comes directly to me, and are one of the first things I do each day.